# Why are my input fields getting reset

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a problem with Javascript, maybe even html...

I've got a code which looks like this:

```
function tafelToetsen() {
  tafel = document.getElementById('tafelToetsen').value;
  if (tafel != "") {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("<table id='table' border='1' onload='dyslectie();'><th colspan='2'>Dit is de tafel van " + tafel + "</th></table>");
    for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      antwoorden[i] = i * tafel;
      document.getElementById('table').innerHTML+=("<tr><td>" + i + " x " + tafel + " =</td><td><input type='text' id='tafel" + i + "' required></td></tr>");
    }

    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML+=("<button onclick='checkToets()'>Check toets</button>");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("Kies je tafel<br/>");
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML+=("<button onclick='checkToets()'>Check toets</button>")
  }
}


// Tafels checken

function checkToets() {
  var naam = document.getElementById('naams').value;

  o = 0;
  v = 0;
  antwoorden[i] = i * tafel;
  for (i = 1; i < antwoorden.length; i++) {
    if ($("#tafel" + i).val() == "" || $("#tafel" + i).val() == null) {
      break;
    } 
    else if (antwoorden[i] != $("#tafel" + i).val()) {
      o++;
    } 
    else {
      v++;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('response').innerHTML+= "";
  if ((v + o) != 10) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("<p id='onvoldoende' style='color:red;'>Je hebt nog niet alles ingevuld," + naam + '.');
  } 
    else if (v == 1) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("Je hebt een 1, " + naam + ", dat moet je zeker verbeteren!");
  }
  else if (v == 2) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("Je hebt een 2, " + naam + ", dat moet je zeker verbeteren!");
  }
  else if (v == 3) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("Je hebt een 3, " + naam + ", dat moet je zeker verbeteren!");
  }
  else if (v == 4) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("Je hebt een 4, " + naam + ", dat moet je zeker verbeteren!");
  }
  else if (v == 5) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("Je hebt een 5,  " + naam + ", een 6 is een voldoende!</p>");
  }
  else if (v == 6) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("<p id='voldoende'>Je hebt een 6, " + naam + ", je hebt NET een voldoende! Oefen meer!");
  }
  else if (v == 7) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("Je hebt een 7, " + naam + ", je hebt een ruimvoldoende! We gaan voor de 10!");
  }
  else if (v == 8) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("Je hebt een 8 gehaald, " + naam + ", zeer goed! Bij de 10 krijg je een certificaat!");
  }
  else if (v == 9) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=("Je hebt een 9 gehaald, " + naam + ", zeer goed! Bijna een 10, dan krijg je een certificaat!");
  }
  else if (v == 10) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML+=("Je hebt alles goed! Goedzo, " + naam + "</p>. <button>Print certificaat!</button>");
  }



}
```

The function checkToets, is checking the input fields for the correct answers, afterwards he's writing a line of html: innerhtml...

But whenever I click the button, the input fields are getting reset.. Searched for a hour on internet for the solution, but couldn't find the right answer..

I still don't have any questions since days... Please help me out of this hell :-)

The html for who requested it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl" ng-app>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tafels Toetsen | Tayfun Kayahan</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicone.ico">
</head>

<body onload="msieversion();">
    <Header>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" id="logo"></a>

        <nav id="navigatie">

        <ul>
            <li id="toetsen">
                <a href="#">TAFELS TOETSEN</a>  

            </li>
            <li id="oefenen">
                <a href="oefenen.html">TAFELS OEFENEN</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="over.html">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
        <img src="images/d.png" id="d" onclick="dyslectie()">

        <p id="dys">Dyslexie</p>
    </Header>
<div id="toetsen">
    <h2>Tafels Toetsen</h2>
    <label id="naamask">Wat is je naam?                </label>
        <input type="text" id="naams" ng-model='naams'><br/>
    <label>Kies je tafel:                </label>
<select name="tafelToetsen" id="tafelToetsen" ng-model='select' type='select'>
      <option value="">Kies een Tafel</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
</select>
    <button id="toetsbutton" type="button" onclick="tafelToetsen()" style="margin-left:3.65%;">Toets de tafel {{ select }}</button><br/>

    <label for="Tafel">Kies je tafel boven de 13:</label>
    <input type="text" name="tafel" id="tafele" ng-model="antwoord">
    <button onclick="expert()">Toets de tafel {{ antwoord }}</button>
</div>
    <div id="response"></div>
    <div id="uitkomst"></div>
<div id="footert">
    <footer>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Twitter</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <a href="#">Facebook</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
            <span class="copy">&copy;2014 <a href="http://www.tkayahan.ict-idcollege.nl/niemandtafels">Wonder<span class="red">S</span><span class="green">Q</span><span class="black">o</span><span class="pink">o</span>l</a>
</footer>
</div>


  <!-- scripts -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/ie.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is there a form wrapping this?

Comment: In many browsers, a `<button>` without a [type attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) will default to `type=submit`. Is the button submitting a form which refreshes the page and resets inputs? If so, you'll want to prevent the submission. One method is to set `<button type="button">`.

Comment: Another sidenote: Don't use raw javascript is you have jQuery!

Comment: @showdev did try, didn't work :( P.S. the page is not refreshing, just thought maybe because the innerHMTL+= the form is resetting, but asked my teacher already and he also didn't have any answer.

Comment: Ok. It's difficult to debug your code unless you can provide an example that reproduces your problem. Please show your HTML and other relevant code. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to be enough to reproduce the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/6q5x7ru5/

Comment: hmmm, kay... Anyways thanks for helping so quickly.. Will try to figure out whats wrong with the code..

Answer (score 0):

It's the line below in your checkToets() function that is reseting the inputs. It replaces the existing html with the same structure, minus your input, but with the addition of an empty string.

```
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML+= "";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still didn't fix the problem.. I'm kinda out of clues right now how to deal with it :/

Comment: Using your code, removing that line resolved the issue for me. Admittedly, I did not have the ie.js script, so maybe that's part of the issue.

Comment: That could be the problem yes, I'll try. Thanks for the help :-)